# Cordova restart application after opening google maps url externaly

Tags: android, jquery, google-maps, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm working with cordova(Latest) and JQM(Latest) application here i stuck with strange issue.

When i open map URL using(inAppBrowser plugin installed)

```
onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/maps/?saddr='"+window.localStorage.getItem("langtitude")+','+window.localStorage.getItem("longtitude")+"'&daddr='"+clstr.lat_lon+"', '_system')"
```

IT Opened successfully but when i get back to application it start from the first.

Note:-->All other website external link works perfectly.

Please advise.

Thanks for your time and consideration in advance and feel free to ask for more info if needed.

Comment: may be some kind of memory issue

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but It happens only once when opening native maps application once that open successfully(Android 4.4.4, MOTO G XT1033) then other request with same url won't loose the application status(It resumes where it suppose to be).Any suggestions?